# How to get an hidden column value in mRender() function from ajax data source in jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am trying to create a jQuery datatable from a ajax source in asp.net mvc5.
I want to add an extra column for edit and delete which is not in my model class or in ajax data-source.For the edit and delete functionality I need the value of the Id column which I have not shown in my datatable.

Here is my Model class:

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country Code Name Must not be empty")]
    public String Code { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country Name Must not be empty")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Template Name Must not be empty")]
    public String Template { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "SPViews Name Must not be empty")]
    public String SPViews { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetAll(JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {
        var countryList = _repository.GetAll().ToList();
        var filteredCountry = (from e in countryList
                               where (param.sSearch == null || e.Name.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()))
                               select e).ToList();
        var result = from country in filteredCountry.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength)
                     select new[] { country.Id,country.Code, country.Name, country.Template, country.SPViews };

        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = countryList.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredCountry.Count,
            aaData = result
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

here is my html table:

```
<table id="countryListTable" class="table table-condensed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Template</th>
        <th>SPViews</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and lastly here is my jQuery code:

```
     var countryTable = $("#countryListTable").dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Country/GetAll",
            "aoColumns": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                {     // fifth column (Edit link)
                    "mData": "Id",
                    "bSearchable": false,
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "mRender": function (nRow, aData) {
                        //need to get the Id column value
                        return '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" href="/Country/Edit/">Edit</a><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" href="/Country/Delete/">Delete</a>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mg1075 thank you for your reply. **fnRender** function seems to be [deprecated](http://datatables.net/usage/columns). I did not try your solution, but I fixed it another way using **mRender** function.
So here is my solution:

```
      countryTable = $("#countryListTable").dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Country/GetAll",
            "aoColumns": [
                 { "bVisible": false },
                  null,
                  null,
                  null,
                  null,
                  {
                      mData: 0,//The Id column
                      "bSearchable": false,
                      "bSortable": false,
                      mRender: function (data, type, row) {

                          return '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" onclick="editCountry(\'/Country/Edit/' + data + '\');return false;">Edit</a><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" onclick="deleteCountry(\'/Country/Delete/' + data + '\');return false;">Delete</a>';
                      }
                  }],

        });
```

I think the both approach should be perfect

Answer (score 3):

First, I would try using `aoColumnDefs` rather than `aoColumns`.
As per the datatables documentation:

http://datatables.net/usage/columns

> **aoColumnDefs**: This array allows you to target a specific column,
>   multiple columns, or all columns, using the aTargets property of each
>   object in the array (please note that aoColumnDefs was introduced in
>   DataTables 1.7). This allows great flexibility when creating tables,
>   as the aoColumnDefs arrays can be of any length, targeting the columns
>   you specifically want.

Next, I cannot quite tell how you intend to use the `Id` in the Edit and Delete links, 
but here the `Id` is appended to the `url`:

```
  "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "mData": "Code ", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
        { "mData": "Name", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
        { "mData": "Template", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
        { "mData": "SPViews", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },               
        { "mData": "Id", "aTargets": [ 4 ], 
            "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                return '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" href="/Country/Edit/' + data + '">Edit</a><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" href="/Country/Delete/' + data + '">Delete</a>';
            }
        },
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 4 ] }
    ],
```

...and here the `Id` appears as a **[data- attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)** whose value you could access, for instance, with jquery:

```
  "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "mData": "Code ", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
        { "mData": "Name", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
        { "mData": "Template", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
        { "mData": "SPViews", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },               
        { "mData": "Id", "aTargets": [ 4 ], 
            "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                return '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-countryid="' + data +'" href="/Country/Edit/">Edit</a><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-countryid="' + data +'" href="/Country/Delete/">Delete</a>';
            }
        },
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 4 ] }
    ],
```