# get cell value in mRender

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I know this question has been asked several times. including this particular [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448206/how-to-get-an-hidden-column-value-in-mrender-function-from-ajax-data-source-in)

I think I'm doing everything right, but I can can't get the value of the first column.

http://localhost/Users/Details/[missing]

```
var InitiatizeUser = function() {
  return {
    init: function() {
      var oTable = $('#users').dataTable({
        "dom": "flt<'row DTTTFooter'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
        "aaSorting": [
          [1, 'asc']
        ],
        "language": {
          "search": "",
          "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_",
          "oPaginate": {
            "sPrevious": "Prev",
            "sNext": "Next"
          }
        },
        "aoColumns": [{
            "bVisible": false,
            "bSearchable": false,
            "bSortable": false,
          },
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null, {
            mData: 0,
            "bSearchable": false,
            "bSortable": false,
            sClass: "alignCenter",
            "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
              return "<a href='/Details/'" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Details'><i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href='/Edit/'" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Edit'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href='/Delete/'" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Delete'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a>";
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    }
  }
}();

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="users">
  <thead class="bordered-darkorange">
    <tr role="row">
      <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppUsers[0].Id)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppUsers[0].Name)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppUsers[0].Email)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppUsers[0].Group)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppUsers[0].Role)
      </th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var user in @Model.AppUsers) {
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.Raw(user.Id)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.Raw(user.Name)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.Raw(user.Email)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.Raw(user.Group)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.Raw(user.Role)
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you put a console log in mRender callback to know what exactly `data` have?

Comment: Just tried console log: actually it is getting the right value: "8e4acedb-dc85-415b-8cb5-fe9c1e7fd766"

Comment: Should it be `return "<a href='/Details/" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Details'><i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href='/Edit/" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Edit'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href='/Delete/" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Delete'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a>";`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have extra single quotes, use the code below:

```
"mRender": function(data, type, full) {
    return "<a href='/Details/" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Details'><i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href='/Edit/" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Edit'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href='/Delete/" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Delete'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a>";
}
```